# Causative Verb with the verb 'relax' but not 'refresh'

Tags: causative-verbs

My Chinese student asked me a question. 
Why is the first sentence incorrect but the second is fine?

1. Music can make me REFRESH.
2. Music can make me relax.

Can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

***Refresh*** is usually a transitive verb, which means that in the indicative or infinitive moods it must take a direct object.

Thus **"Music refreshes me"** would be perfectly correct.

However ***relax*** is usually intransitive - and no object is required. Though it can also, less frequently, be transitive. So you could say **"Music relaxes me"**.

This is why you can say **"I relax on Thusdays"**, but you wouldn't normally say **"I refresh on Thursdays"** - though in everyday colloquial speech you may hear ***refresh*** used intransitively. **"I usually refresh before going out in the evenings"** - though it is not very common.

Comment: OK. I understand. But why can we then say: "Music makes me feel refreshed" but not "Music makes me refresh \ refreshed"? I appreciate your help.

Comment: @PeterWilliams Because in that example *refreshed* is being used as an adverb qualifying the infinitive *feel*. But *refresh* is an infinitive, and as a transitive verb it won't work without an object.